# limit continuity for value K does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

$$f(x) := \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2+2kx+1}{x+1}  & \text{for $x$ < -1}, \\[2ex]
x^2+2 & \text{for $x$ $\ge$ -1}.
\end{cases}$$
I tried using L'Hopital, but after seeing it in desmos, the graph doesn't seem to be continuous at the point that I got.

Comment: Please edit your query, removing the graphics link and instead using MathJax to place the math in your query.  Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Comment: How did you use L'Hopital, and what point did you get?

Comment: @player3236 I got K = 2.5 then I tested on desmos but it doesn't seem to be the answer

Comment: I got $k = -1/2$. Can I ask why you think you need to use L'Hopital first?

Comment: I didn't even see the $x+1$ on the denominator my mistake. Are you saying we are given that the function is continuous at $x=-1$ and we must find $k$?

Comment: @DerekLuna Yess

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that in the problem it is given that the function is continous in its domain

so $\lim_{x \to -1}f(x)$  must exist
$\Rightarrow (-1)^2 - 2k \ + \ 1 = 0 $

which gives $k=1$

so $\lim_{x \to -1^-} f(x) = 0 \neq f(-1) $

so $f$ is continous for no value of k

Comment: Why does the first expression equal $0$? Not to mention continuity would imply it actually equals $3$ and you forgot the $x+1$ in the denominator as well?

Comment: @DerekLuna You are missing the underlying idea in Aditya Dwivedi's answer.  At $x = -1$, the denominator of $f(x) = (x + 1) = 0.$  Therefore, if, at $x= -1$ the numerator of $f(x)$ evaluates to **any non-zero** number, then at $x = -1$, $f(x)$ will automatically evaluate as **unbounded**.  So the requirement that at $x = -1$, the numerator of $f(x)$ evaluate to $0$ supercedes all other considerations.